# Unrar specific .rar file from multipart list without automatically iterating through the list

Tags: rar

I was wondering, since executing `unrar -x file.part01.rar 123.zip destinationPath` would automatically iterate through the list until the file `123.zip` is found, is there a way to stop that auto search for multivolume archives?

For example, I have a set of 100parts of a multipart volume, it would take some time to find the file if the file were to be located at part51. Instead, I would like to generate two processes that starts at part1 and the other starts at part50. If I were to execute `unrar -x file.part50.rar 123.zip destinationPath`, it skips `part50` and starts over to the top.

Second option, if possible, is there a way I can just execute `unrar -x file.part50.rar 123.zip destinationPath` and if file is not found exit/stop process and start a new command execution `unrar -x file.part51.rar 123.zip destinationPath`.

Any suggestions or advice would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the **solid** archive type, when creating the archives:

> A solid archive is a RAR archive packed by a special compression
> method, which treats all files, within the archive, as one continuous
> data stream.
>
> (...)
>
> But it also has a few important disadvantages:
>
> - slower updating of existing solid archives
> - **to extract a single file from a solid archive all preceding files must be analyzed.** This makes
>   extraction from the middle of a solid archive slower than extraction
>   from a normal archive, but, if all files are to be extracted from a
>   solid archive, the extraction speed will not be affected.
>   (...)

source:
http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/

Comment: Thank you for the response, Michael. I believe there is really no workaround to it if I wanted to skim through a solid archive type. I just wanted to make the search quicker for my current project and the multipart is mandatory for this since those volumes are not mine and I cannot modify their process. If anyone has any suggestions, that would be great. But as it stands, looks like I would have to stick with the current solution. Starting at the top.